# Visual Studio 2015 can not launch Android Simulator(Hyper-V)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

My Visual Studio 2015 can not launch Android Simulator. It appear the hyper-v error message, even I on/off hyper-v in control panel feature UI.
 Could somebody know how to solve this problem? I attach the error message picture.

The emulator is unable to verify the virtual machine is running
[Open emulator problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlMk3.jpg)

```
log
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:57:29 : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:57:29 : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:57:29 : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:57:29 : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:57:32 : [Informational] Launching emulator...
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:58:06 : [Critical] Could not launch 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device. Exit code 10.
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:58:06 : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:58:06 : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5 /video "1080x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\akira_mac\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_KitKat_(4.4)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.akira_mac"
 3> 2016/5/17 下午 10:58:06 : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: CouldntStartVm (10)
```

[image]

Comment: As per your image it is clear that Hyper-V Component is not working properly or some of the Hyper-V feature is turned on .

Comment: I cannot enable Hyper Hyperisor in the windows features. I use MacBook with parallel desktop installed windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You should "Enable Nested Virtualization" in the configuration of your Parallels Desktop Virtual machine.

Go to Actions menu ► Configure ► Hardware ► CPU&Memory. Expand "Advanced Settings" and tick Enable Nested Virtualization checkbox.

see http://kb.parallels.com/en/116239  for more details.